# The sum of two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the following vector spaces. If $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$

$$V=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}|ax+by+cz=0\}$$
$$W=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}|ax+by-cz=0\}$$

I want to find $V+W$. Is $V+W=\{(x,y,z)|ax+by+cz=0\,\,\, \&\,\,\,ax+by-cz=0\}$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $V+W$?

Comment: @EricWofsey the sum of alll linear combinations of $V$ and $W$

Comment: by definition if $x\in V+W$ then exists some $v\in V$ and some $w\in W$ such that $x=v+w$. Your definition of $V+W$ is wrong, you are using the same $x,y$ and $z$ for both spaces at once.